# Exercise of applying Ito's Lemma

Tags: probability, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

*Let ${(X_{t})}_{t\geq 0}$ a stochastic process that evolves with dynamic $\frac{dX_{t}}{X_{t}}=(t+1)dt+\frac{1}{2}dW_{t}$. Determine the stochastic differential of process $Y_{t}=X_{t}e^{-\frac{1}{2}[(t+1)^2]}$.*

---

Trivially, i have to calculate $\frac{\partial Y_{t}}{\partial t}$, $\frac{\partial Y_{t}}{\partial X_{t}}$ and $\frac{\partial ^{2}Y_{t}}{\partial X_{t}^{2}}$ and replace these partial derivatives in $dY_{t}=\frac{\partial Y_{t}}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial Y_{t}}{\partial X_{t}}dX_{t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial ^{2}Y_{t}}{\partial X_{t}^{2}}\left \langle dX_{t},dX_{t} \right \rangle$, right?

Thanks for any possible confirmations.

Comment: Yes, that would be how to do it. If you post an answer we could check it.

Comment: @bitesizebo Thanks for your answer! Now it's late in Italy but tomorrow I post the solution. I just needed to confirm actually, but receive an additional aid could be helpful!

Comment: I hope you don't forget about writing the solution I don't understand this subject well so it would be helpful, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y_{t}=X_{t}e^{-\frac{1}{2}[(t+1)]^{2}}$. So:

- $\frac{\partial Y_{t}}{\partial t}=-e^{-\frac{1}{2}[(t+1)]^{2}}(t+1)$
- $\frac{\partial Y_{t}}{\partial X_{t}}=e^{-\frac{1}{2}[(t+1)]^{2}}$
- $\frac{\partial^2 Y_{t}}{\partial X_{t}^2}=0$

Replacing in Ito's SDE:

$dY_{t}=\frac{\partial Y_{t}}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial Y_{t}}{\partial X_{t}}dX_{t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 Y_{t}}{\partial X_{t}^2}\left \langle dX_t,dX_t \right \rangle=e^{-\frac{1}{2}[(t+1)]^2}[(t+1)+(t+1)X_tdt+\frac{1}{2}X_tdW_t]$.

I wait for confirmations!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Almost there! More rigorously, you should apply the Ito lemma to the function $f(t,x)=xe^{-\frac{1}{2}(t+1)^{2}}$ as $Y_t = f(t,X_t)$. So $\partial_x f(t,x)= e^{-\frac{1}{2}(t+1)^{2}} = f(t,x)/x$, $\partial_{xx} f(t,x)=0$  and $\partial_tf(t,x) = -x(t+1)e^{-\frac{1}{2}(t+1)^{2}} = -(t+1)f(t,x)$. 
So $dY_t = \partial_tf(t,X_t)dt + \partial_xf(t,x)dX_t= -Y_t(t+1)dt + Y_t(t+1) +1/2 Y_tdW_t$. Finally, $dY_t = 1/2Y_tdW_t$.

Comment: @Sesame Thanks for your answer. I'm wrong the derivative against time, ok. Too much superficiality. The rest is correct, right?

Comment: Took me some time to understand what was going here but taking in consideration what Sesame said it seems correct to me at least, thanks again